# Java problem: cannot be referenced from static context ( in constract algorithm binary search tree )

Tags: java, static

When I assign new value to my binary search tree the same way my input method function do, program report error say cannot be referenced from static context. (this line `a.root.left = new Node("dd",22)` say Node is not static [image]

this is my program:

```
package trylang;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class tryBSTnode<Key extends Comparable<Key>, Value> {
    private Node root;
    private class Node{
        private Key key;
        private Value value;
        private Node left, right;
        public Node(Key key, Value val){
            this.key = key;
            this.value = val;
        }
    }
    public tryBSTnode(){

    }

    public void put(Key key, Value val){
        root = put(root,key,val);
    }

    public Node put(Node nd, Key key, Value val){
        if (nd == null) return new Node(key, val);
        int cmp = key.compareTo(nd.key);
        if (cmp>0) nd.right = put(nd.right,key,val);
        else if (cmp<0) nd.left = put(nd.left, key, val);
        else nd.value = val;
        return nd;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        tryBSTnode<String, Integer> a = new tryBSTnode<String, Integer>();
        a.put("aa",20);
        a.put("bb",67);
        a.put("cc",67);
        a.root.left = new Node("dd",22); //this line got problem
    }
}
```

The put method logic is that when node is null, we can assign a new node to it.

```
 public Node put(Node nd, Key key, Value val){
        if (nd == null) return new Node(key, val);
        int cmp = key.compareTo(nd.key);
        if (cmp>0) nd.right = put(nd.right,key,val);
        else if (cmp<0) nd.left = put(nd.left, key, val);
        else nd.value = val;
        return nd;
    }
```

The tree structure would be like root(aa,20)->right(bb,67)->right(cc,67), and run the put method do not meet any error. The left side of root is null. However, when I want to assign a new node to left side of tree, itellij say this line  `a.root.left = new Node("dd",22)`    cannot be referenced from static context. Why this line can work in put method, but have error in the main method?

Comment: I would suggest you to extract the `Node` class to another file and make it a public class instead of an inner class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Node` is an inner class, having a `tryBSTNode.this` besides `this`, with which it can access members - fields or methods - of a `tryBSTNode` object.

As that binding of Node is not intended, make it static:

```
private static class Node {
```

Or move the class outside tryBSTNode; you are allowed to have additional non-public classes in one source.

Or make a separate source.

---

You should have named your main class `TryBSTNode`. It also looks a bit like a unit test, Test Driven Development. You might look into that, eventually.

Answer (score 1):

As the error says; you can't access non-static members (Node) from statics context (the main method). Put the Node class out of tryBSTNode class and it works.